# Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP

Tags: java, servlets, server, weblogic, weblogic12c

Can some one help me understand why I'm getting this error while running my managed server locally. My admin server is also running (locally as well) on port 7001.

Why it is trying to connect **172.30.XXX.XXX** ip ? I am but confused what's happening here. When I startup my managed server I get this exception.

```
   INFO: The Wsee Service is starting
    java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '172.30.XXX.XXX', port: '7001'
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:401)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:506)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:313)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:289)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:267)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.HttpDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(HttpDataTransferHandler.java:76)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: I've disabled my system's firewall as well.

Comment: What port is your managed server running on? Does it come up in an `Admin` mode? Are there other errors in the logs about deployments on that server?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, how did you solve this issue. Thanks in advance :)